How to select a root to FindRoot to define an implicit function?
I have the following implicit function utilising the FindRoot function in Mathematica
phi[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, mc_?NumericQ, ms_?NumericQ] := 
 FindRoot[-((1 - Lambda)*mc + Sqrt[alpha]*x)*
      Sin[phi] + ((1 - Lambda)*ms + Sqrt[alpha]*y)*Cos[phi] - 
     alpha*(C2*Sin[phi]*Sin[phi] - S1*Cos[phi]*Cos[phi] + (C1 - S2)*Cos[phi]*Sin[phi]), 
     {phi, 3.1}][[1]][[2]]

However, depending on some values, if one were to find all roots, one can get up to four roots, showing an example here,
Plot[{0.2-0.9*Sin[0.1+x]-0.1*Cos[0.1+x], 0.2+(Sin[x+1])^2 +Sin[x+1]*Cos[x+1]-Cos[x+1]^(2)}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}]


I want to select a root that spans the largest intersection area, with the "red" line above the "blue" line. So in this case the root near x=6.
I know a crude way to take care of the second condition, but first one is giving be some trouble.
expr1[x_] := 0.2 - 0.9*Sin[0.1 + x] - 0.1*Cos[0.1 + x];
expr2[x_]:= 0.2+(Sin[x+1])^2 +Sin[x+1]*Cos[x+1]-Cos[x+1]^2;

xVal = NSolve[{expr1[x]- expr2[x]==0 && expr1[x-0.002] >expr2[x-0.002], 0 <= x<=2*Pi}, x, Reals] // FullSimplify // Union

Plot[{expr1[x], expr2[x]}, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Red}, {Thick, Blue}},
 Epilog -> {black, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[{x,expr1[x]} /. xVal]}, Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {Yellow, Transparent}}}]



phi[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, mc_?NumericQ, ms_?NumericQ] := 
Module[{phiVar, solutions}, solutions = NSolve[ { -((1 - 0.5)*mc + 
Sqrt[0.1]*x)*Sin[phiVar] + ((1 - 0.5)*ms + Sqrt[0.1]*y)*Cos[phiVar] ==
 0.1*(0.1*Sin[phiVar]*Sin[phiVar] - 0.1*Cos[phiVar]*Cos[phiVar] + (0.1 - 0.1)*Cos[phiVar]*Sin[phiVar]) && { -((1 - 0.5)*mc + 
Sqrt[0.1]*x)*Sin[phiVar] + ((1 - 0.5)*ms + Sqrt[0.1]*y)*Cos[phiVar] >
 0.1*(0.1*Sin[phiVar]*Sin[phiVar] - 0.1*Cos[phiVar]*Cos[phiVar] + (0.1 - 0.1)*Cos[phiVar]*Sin[phiVar]), 0 <= phiVar <= 2*Pi }, phiVar, Reals ]; solutions ]


Are you asking for something like this that finds the largest root interval by area between the curves?

@ydd, Yes! Thank you very much!

Ok, I addded my nb as an answer

Using your example of
expr1[x_] := 0.2 - 0.9*Sin[0.1 + x] - 0.1*Cos[0.1 + x];
expr2[x_]:= 0.2+(Sin[x+1])^2 +Sin[x+1]*Cos[x+1]-Cos[x+1]^2;
diff[x_] := expr1[x] - expr2[x];

We find where the two functions are equal:
roots = NSolveValues[{diff[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2*Pi}, x]
(*{1.58012, 2.53718, 3.90032, 5.90464}*)

create the interval endpoints:
intervals = Partition[roots, 2, 1]

(*{{1.58012, 2.53718}, {2.53718, 3.90032}, {3.90032, 5.90464}}*)

Select  the  intervals  where  diff > 0  at  the  midpoint:
intervals = Select[intervals, diff[Mean[#]] > 0 &]

(*{{1.58012, 2.53718}, {3.90032, 5.90464}}*)

Define a function that calculates the area between the curves:
areaBetween := NIntegrate[diff[x], {x, #[[1]], #[[2]]}] &;

and select the interval with the largest areaBetween:
largestByArea = First@TakeLargestBy[intervals, areaBetween, 1]

(*{3.90032, 5.90464}*)


Hi, sorry for a late request, is there way to put a fallback in case there are only two roots? Then the execution ends in step-II? Thank you very much.

Add a condition so that the Select step is only done if there's more than one root interval:
intervals =   If[Length@intervals > 1, Select[intervals, diff[Mean[#]] > 0 &], intervals]
